# Cómo insertar un diseño en css y div a una respuesta de una función?

Tags: php, html, css

Me gustaría saber como hacer esto:

Tengo este código:

```
<?php
/*Incluyendo la conexion y enviando el Arreglo Files a la funcion*/
include 'coneccion.php';
if ( isset($_POST['save']) ){
  $DBImagen->uploadImage($_FILES);
}

/*Llamando a la función para visualizar las imagenes*/
$DBImagen->viewImages();
```

Esto me funciona a la perfección esto me muestra imágenes que tengo guardadas en mi base de datos.

Copio imagen de como se ve:
[image: como se ve]

Entonces a esto me gustaría darle un poco de formato, entonces tengo esto.

Primero mediante div se organiza un poco:

```
<div class="producto">
  <div class="name_producto"><?=$r['name']?>"/></div>
  <div><img class="img_producto" src="productosima/<?= $r^['imagen'] ?>"/></div>
</div>
```

Luego con estilo.css se le da formato:

```
.producto{
  display: inline-block;
  width:25%;
  padding:10px;
  background: rgba(0,0,00.05);
  color:#333;
  margin:5px;
}

.img_producto{
  width:100%;
}

.name_producto{
  padding:10px;
  color:#fff;
  background:#ff0000;
  text-align: center;
  font-size:18px;
}
```

PREGUNTA: Cómo puedo incorporar estos formatos y estilos al código de arriba del todo, que se me muestren las imágenes con el formato que yo le de.

El problema que tengo es que no lo puedo vincular.

Gracias de antemano. El código CSS lo he obtenido de un canal de youtube de aprendizaje de libre edición (AnySlehider)

ACTUALIZACIÓN

Aquí es la posición de las imagenes que no puedo obtener.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los cuadros azules serian las imagenes.

Comment: Entiendo que el problema que tienes es que no muestra correctamente el tamaño de las imagenes dentro del div. Teniendo en cuenta que cada imagen tiene diferentes tamaños...

Comment: el problema es que me gustaria que estubiera en bloques, muchas páginas web cuando muestran entradas de escritos lo muestran en unos recuadros bien posicionados, cuatro arriba otros cuatro abajo i así seguidamente. Perdona por la tardia, tuve problemas con el ordenador.

Comment: He hecho una actualización, si le pueden hacer un vistazo... gracias de antemano

Comment: Tienes el css en un fichero aparte? Has pensado en que puede que el estilo no se aplique debido a ello?. Le pones un ```background``` y no ejecuta ese background... También se nota que el ```.producto``` ocupa el 100% de la ventana por lo que es muy probable que el ```display:inline-block``` no funcione como deberia

Comment: Para saber si ejecuta bien el css haz lo siguiente: ``click derecho > inspeccionar elemento``

Comment: vale voy a probarlo

Comment: He encontrado lo que queria en otra pregunta en stackoverflow, pero ahora el problema que tengo es que no puedo enlazarlo. Te paso el link. https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/279015/131216  Gracias por ayudarme te lo agradezco mucho. Si quieres echarle un vistazo.