# Cómo poner un estilo con cajas (div) a un resultado imprimido de una búsqueda en la base de datos?

Tags: php, html, css

tengo una duda, yo hago una búsqueda en mi base de datos hi me sale esto. (Són imagenes que tengo en la base guardadas mediante ruta, entonces...)

[image: Lo que me sale]

Código:

```html
<?php 
                     /*Incluyendo la conexion y enviando el Arreglo Files a la funcion*/
 include 'coneccion.php';
 if(isset($_POST['save']))
 {
  $DBImagen->uploadImage($_FILES);
    }
    
                    /*Llamando a la función para visualizar las imagenes*/
                    
                    $DBImagen->viewImages();
  ?>
```

Me ayudan a ensenyarme cómo ponerle un estilo, que aparezcan horizontales cuatro arriba, otras cuatro abajo y así consecutivamente hasta que no hayan mas resultados. Eso si tiene que estar en cajas (div), a mi cliente no le vale en tablas.

Comment: Con el código en PHP que nos compartes no podemos hacer mucho, podrías compartir el HTML y el CSS que usas para mostrar tus imágenes. T

Comment: Perdón @Jheyman Mejia, aquí el link de la pregunta original. https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/277233/131216