# Enlazar los card de bootstrap con bases de datos que maneja phpmyadmin

Tags: php, html, css, bootstrap

Tengo el siguiente problema. Yo tengo unos archivos de imágenes guardadas en una base de datos. Las imágenes están guardadas mediante ruta.

La base de datos es `mysqli`.

He estado buscando y he encontrado esto de los `cards` de `bootstrap`, entonces explico la situación que me `gustaria` crear.

Usuario hace una búsqueda en mi blog fotográfico.

Al usuario al darle al botón de buscar saldrán un X de resultados.

Entonces ahora me gustaría que me ayudarais a enlazar el diseño de los `card` de `bootstrap` con las imágenes que salgan.

PROBLEMA:
No logro que los card me enseñen las imágenes que yo tengo guardadas mediante ruta en mi base de datos phpmyadmin. Aquí que pasa, si yo tengo 6 imagenes se tendrían que aparecer seis card, si tengo siete tendrian que aparecer 7 card.

NOTA:
Si tienen algún otro modelo que prefieren al mostar esas imagenes, no duden en comentar-lo, estoy abierto a todo tipo de sugerencias.

CODIGO:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```html
 <div class="row mx-auto p-3">
    
            <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
                <div class="card ">
                    <img src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,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"
                         class="card-img-top" alt="Card image"/>
    
                    <div class="card-block">
                        <h4 class="card-title">This is a title</h4>
                        <p class="card-text">Each merged squad salts the wild porter. Should the charmed church dodge a
                            camera? The gown litters the rhyme. Another discrete elevator defects over the target.</p>
                        <a href="" class="btn btn-success">Button</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
                <div class="card">
                    <img src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,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"
                         class="card-img-top" alt="Card image"/>
    
                    <div class="card-block">
                        <h4 class="card-title">This is a title</h4>
                        <p class="card-text">Each merged squad salts the wild porter. Should the charmed church dodge a
                            camera? The gown litters the rhyme. Another discrete elevator defects over the target.</p>
                        <a href="" class="btn btn-success">Button</a>
                    </div>
                </div> 
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
                <div class="card .img-fluid">
                    <img src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,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"
                         class="card-img-top" alt="Card image"/>
    
                    <div class="card-block">
                        <h4 class="card-title">This is a title</h4>
                        <p class="card-text">Each merged squad salts the wild porter. Should the charmed church dodge a
                            camera? The gown litters the rhyme. Another discrete elevator defects over the target.</p>
                        <a href="" class="btn btn-success">Button</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        function showHide() {
            $('#text1').slideToggle();
    
            $('#text2').slideToggle();
            $('#boton').slideToggle();
        }
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            $(".oculto").hide();
            $(".inf").click(function () {
                var nodo = $(this).attr("href");
    
                if ($(nodo).is(":visible")) {
                    $(nodo).hide();
                    return false;
                } else {
                    $(".oculto").hide("slow");
                    $(nodo).fadeToggle("fast");
                    return false;
                }
            });
        });
    
    
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

ACTUALIZACIÓN:

Aquí tengo el código de como muestro las imagenes (Estas no tienen ningun estilo ni nada):

```html
<?php 
                     
    include 'coneccion.php';
    if(isset($_POST['save']))
    {
        $DBImagen->uploadImage($_FILES);
    }
    
                    /*Llamando a la función para visualizar las imagenes*/
                    
                    $DBImagen->viewImages();
  ?>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Como generas el src de cada imagen? dudo que en tu base de datos hayas guardado eso como ruta...

Comment: lo muestro como una función. $DBImagen->viewImages();  Que es así include 'coneccion.php';
 if(isset($_POST['save']))
 {
  $DBImagen->uploadImage($_FILES);
 }

Comment: pero si guardaste eso en la base,entonces no guardaste la ruta, guardaste el archivo.. puede ser?

Comment: Veo que eres un crack en mysqli. ya se que se desvia un poco del contexto pero en algun comentario si tu quieres claro me podrias decir si eso que hago está bien para mostrar los datos. Si tienes tu propio blog o algo me encantaria pasarme para aprender.

Comment: Se me guarda en una carpeta imagenes y las imagenes se guardan en la misma carpeta. Te paso imagen.

Comment: Por lo que entiendo ahí... Estas guardando la imagen como un fichero en la base de datos. No? Y son imágenes SVG.

Comment: PHPMyAdmin no es un gestor de bases de datos. Solo es una herramienta hecha en PHP que maneja una BD MySQL o Maria DB. Por favor edita la pregunta.

Comment: Cambie la pregunta, y matahombres lo de imagenes de SVG no sé. I las imagenes en un fitchero no entiendo muy bien ya que se guarda en imagenes/(nombre de la imagen) Lo de los vectores es por el nombre e la foto? Si es por eso al final tiene la terminación .png es solo seguridad lo del nombre tan largo.

Comment: que hace la funcion viewImages?? que es DBImagen? en mi perfil tenes toda mi informacion. Como guardas el archivo en la base de datos? podrias mostrar algunos registros de lo que vos decis que son las rutas al archivo? el src deberia apuntar a una url de tu sitio que tenga la imagen... eso que vos escribis en la card no es una url de nada, es como si estuviera embebida en la app (si fuera una SPA).

Comment: Lo de la SPA es como la imagen de 380·380 que sale en la foto, yo tampoco se como va eso, eso algo estandard que se puede cambiar, mi pregunta es como puedo hacer yo para que se cambien esos datos por los de mi base de datos. (titulo, descripcion, precio, etc) sabes? Ahora te paso el codigo de como inserto las imagenes.

Comment: Vale, he puesto las funciones, creo y voy a intentar modificar la DBImagen para que se muestren como yo quiera. Si sabeis algo decirmelo porque ando un poco perdido. Quiero mostrar mis resultados en los card, y si no se puede en alguna otra forma pero que se semejante diseño. Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontré la respuesta hace tiempo y la voy a compartir para futuras referencias para otros usuarios.

Hay que insertar donde uno quiera ver el texto importado esta `$img`:

```
<?php print($img['nombre que hay en la base de datos']); ?>
```

Y la `$img` la saldrá de aquí, un simple `SELECT` en `pdo` que mediante un while guardará los datos en img:

```
$SQLStatement = $this->DBConexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM catenombre");
        $SQLStatement->execute();
    
        while($img = $SQLStatement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
```

La variable `$img` contiene los datos de tu tabla de datos, que tu al poner  `<?php print($img['nombre que hay en la base de datos']); ?>` se insertaran en tu objeto creado. Cada linea será creado un objeto.
Se que esta pregunta es antigua pero cualquier duda hagan un comentario, siempre me gusta editar y mejorar mis antiguas preguntas.